# Windows Store App, Grid View items not displaying

Tags: windows, gridview, windows-8, windows-store-apps, datatemplate

i'm working on a windows 8 app but i'm new to WPF.  I've spend a good day on this but can't figure out why it doesn't work.  Basically I am trying to create a grid view of some images with text at the top.  But only a gradient filled box is displayed, no text or image.

Below is my page which at this moment is very simple.  The image has been added to the project and lives in the Assets folder.

Can anyone please tell me why it doesn't work.

```
<Page
x:Class="App4.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App4"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    <GridView 
        x:Name="GridView1"
        Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="GridView1"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF443585" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontSize="25" Padding="10" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Red"/>
                    <Image Source="Logo.png" Height="100" Width="250" Visibility="Visible"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

</Grid>
```

```
    private void Page_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Item> Temp = new List<Item>() { new Item() { ItemName = "test" }, new Item() { ItemName = "test 2" } };

        GridView1.DataContext = Temp;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define `ItemsSource` for `GridView`

```
GridView1.ItemsSource = Temp;
```

Comment: Ah, ItemSource.  When do we use DataContext? And also in XAML how can I specify an image in the Pictures folder?  I tried "C:\users\<username>\Pictures\MyImage.jpg" where <username> is the user's name. but no image is displayed.  However it works in code behind if I load the image into a stream and and then into a bitmapimage and then assign the image source.

Comment: @Thereisnospoon You need to set the ItemsSouurce, you can set it directly or bind it through data context in XAML, `ItemsSource="{Binding Temp}"`.

Comment: @Thereisnospoon check http://www.codingbeta.com/programatically-setting-image-source-in-metro-style-apps-with-wpf/ for the answer of second question

Answer (score 0):

This is because the GridView always work with ItemsSource not with DataContext property.
GridView.ItemsSource = Temp;